# How to install PWA studio. Magento 2.3.1

Tags: frontend, magento2.3.1, pwa, pwa-studio

I'm using https://hackernoon.com/getting-started-with-magento-pwa-studio-with-poc-c54c33f8d038 this link to use **PWA Venia theme** but when I'm trying to follow these steps then on **step number 3** when I used 
`ln -s /var/www/html/magento/pwa-studio/packages/pwa-module app/code/Magento/` 
 to create a **symlink** then its not creating proper **symlink** so when I check the `pwa-studio/packages/pwa-module` package then there was no any package with the name **pwa-module** n when I run other commands after this one then the command works perfectly but because of this command or may be some other issue the **theme** is not created properly. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

That post from hakernoon is based on an early version of PWA Studio.

Follow the documentation https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/.

You don't need to install a PWA Studio app on the same server as Magento, in most cases you would not.

Comment: but Sir is it will be working on the *localhost* as well??? I'm trying on the localhost

Comment: ok Sir I tried the above link you give to me but there is following issues can you please help me to sort out?
**1** on step 3 I on which we need to give URL I give them `MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL="localhost/magento231"` is it ok?
**2** when I run `deployVeniaSampleData.sh` command then it gives me an error `bash deployVeniaSampleData.sh`<br>
**3** I already downloaded M2.3.1 with sample data did I need the data again for the Venia Theme?Thanks